# How ot select an element in the DOM hierarchy that has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a construction made up of several nested `<div>` and `<input>` components.

When I focus on one of the inputs, I would like to change the background color of the first element in the hierarchy that has the class `note`.

The code below shows the general idea, but it works only for the first (parent) element above the focused-on input.

```js
document.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => changeFocusColor(event))
const changeFocusColor = (event) => {
  // here comes the computation of the element to do ...style.BackgroundColor = ... on
  event.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="note">
    <input />first level
    <div>
      <input />second level
      <input />second level
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

**Is there a clean way to say *"go up in the DOM tree until you find an element with the class `note` and apply a style on it"*?**

The way I plan to do it is to iterate over `element.path` and check its `classList` until I find `note` there, and then apply `style.background` on that element.

Comment: So, you’re looking for [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon: well, that's a clean way, to say the least :) Yes, this is exactly this. Would you be so kind and turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks! EDIT: ah, there is already a duplicate.

Comment: The question’s already closed. This has been asked and answered a few times before.